# What is largest amount of data Python 3 can write at once?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management

I wrote this program to experiment with file size in Python 3.6.2

```
import os

#   Opening a text file a.txt in wite mode.
fp = open("a.txt", "w")

try:
    #   Writing 'a' in multiple of bytes.
    #   One 'a' consumes 1 byte. 
    #   1024*1024 is 1 MB.
    fp.write("a"*1024*1024*418) 

except:
    print("Memory Error.")
fp.close()
```

After 418 MB, program throws ***Memory Error***.

So am I to assume that Python 3 cannot write more than 418 MB at once?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the file size. Write in smaller chunks, and you'll easily be able to go past 418 MB.

Comment: @user2357112: My question is why is it not able to handle file bigger than 418MB ?

Comment: It can, easily.

Comment: @user2357112: Then why is it throwing exception beyond 418MB ?

Comment: You're overloading your memory with a 418 MB string (and with the additional copies and transformed versions of its data involved in the file writing process).

Comment: @user2357112: Please check my modified question.